# Required Services for RDC in Safe Mode?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-10, safe-mode

Does anyone know exactly which Services I need to add to Safe Mode + Networking to be able to RDC into a machine, just on the local subnet?

I've added the ones I thought would do it...

- Remote Desktop Services
- Remote Desktop Services UserMode Port Redirector [which I didn't think was necessary, but was running out of ideas]
- RPC & Locator

I just get the 'couldn't connect, make sure it's switched on' message, which is giving me no clues whatsoever.

Remote machines are running Windows 10, one is clean, the other an update, almost identical hardware.

I've tried RDC from Mac & Windows, same result.

No issues when not running in Safe Mode + Networking.

Or... in order to troubleshoot further, where would the error logs be on the remote machine?